# I Can't use sudo apt install

Tags: apt, uefi, dpkg

When ever i run `sudo apt install` it says:

`E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

but when I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` it says:

`Your system has UEFI Secure boot enabled. UEFI Secure Boot requires additional configuration to work with third-party drivers. The system will assist you in configuring UEFI Secure Boot. To permit the use of third-party drivers, a new Machine-Owner Key (MOK) has been generated. This key now needs to be enrolled in your system's firmware. To ensure that this change is being made by you as an authorized user, and not by an attacker, you must choose a password now and then confirm the change after reboot using the same password, in both the "Enroll MOK" and "Change Secure Boot state" menus that will be presented to you when this system reboots.`

It Started doing that right after I installed Virtualbox

How can I Fix that?

Comment: **It Won't work even though I did what it said**

Comment: @Hoidberg Please [edit] and add more details. How exactly does it not work?

Comment: And what exactly did you do?

Comment: I Tried to fix it but even after doing what it says it still pops up

Comment: OK, but please [edit] your question and add these details. Did you choose a password? Did you reboot? Were the menus actually presented to you? Did you choose the choices described? Did you try the same command after rebooting? Did you get the exact same output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOK Manager

```
sudo mokutil  --disable-validation
Root password:
Password:12345678
Password:12345678
sudo reboot
```

You will boot in MOK Manager = blue screen.

1. The question to answer is YES for disabling secure boot.
   Number shown is password character: 7 is the 7th character of the pasword, keeping 12345678 is safer. Make sure numlock keyboard is enabled and enter numbers.
2. Enroll the key/press enter : EFI/ubuntu/grubx64/OK/Redo for/BOOT/bootx64.efi/OK
3. Enroll hash/press enter: EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi/OK/Redo for/BOOT/bootx64.efi/OK
4. Reboot

On startup, you will see a message saying *booting in insecure mode*. Secure boot will be disabled momentarily on startup.

```
mokutil  --sb-state
```

The same problem occurs when we compile custom kernel with secure boot enabled. We have to disable secure boot only in MOK. No need to enroll key and hash.

```
mokutil  --sb-state
SecureBoot enabled
uname -a
Linux mm 5.0.0-050000rc8-generic #201902242030 SMP Mon Feb 25 01:32:53 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tested on Kernel 5.0-rc8

If 2 and 3 is not working, select secure boot instead in MOK and disable it with the same password. In MOK, disable secure boot at boot time is better and works in all distros.